# Certificate of Citizenship, but no passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, spain

My son will have an Irish Certificate of Citizenship within the next few weeks, hopefully. We're hoping to go to Northern Ireland at the end of the year, and it seems unlikely we'll have time to get him an Irish passport before that. For Ireland, that's not an issue since he has a Bolivian passport, which is visa free there. But, we'll likely have to travel through Spain. As a citizen, will he be able to get a Schengen visa? Or can we travel on his Bolivian passport with the certificate of citizenship? It's a complicated situation.

Comment: This looks like a Travel Stack Exchange question to me.

Comment: @Willeke It would certainly be fine on travel.SE but there is a clear expat angle as well, an Irish citizen by birth would not encounter this problem.

Comment: Where are you traveling from?